# wifi direct android app creation

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I need to develop an android app for communicating tablet wireless. After some google search i found Wifi direct (Wifi P2P) is the solution for that. I have some doubt about this. I found wifi direct option in some Samsung device only.

Is every android device after ICS support Wifi direct? If possible how can i enable wifi  direct service in those devices.

If not,  Which are the wifi direct service available devices?

Can i create one to many network using wifi direct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WiFi direct is supported by most devices with Android 4.0 and above, and you can create one-to-many network with it.